# Does Concealment affect your astral signature/form?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, concealment

I'm not clear on how the Concealment power affects astral forms and signatures. Can it be used to hide them? The rules state that "perceiving magic" is a Perception Test (core, pg 280), but Assensing Tests  don't use Perception (core, pg 312), which is what the Concealment power statistically affects. (Improved) Invisibility specifies that it doesn't do this, but Concealment does not.

Mostly, I ask because I want to determine the practicality of having a spirit use Concealment to hide a character's astral form/signatures from other Awakened (and it's own), rather than learning Masking and/or Extended Masking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No go.

SR5, p. 394, under "Powers", then "Type":

> ...physical powers cannot be used in astral space or to affect astral forms.

Per SR5, p. 395, **Concealment** is a Physical power ("Type: P").

This also means that a spirit must also be **Materialized** (SR5, p. 398) or otherwise present in meatspace to use **Concealment**; it can't hang around in astral space and use the power on people while remaining protected in the astral.